# How do I Use String Aggregate Clause correctly in BigQuery? Redacted

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can't get the STRING_AGG() clause to work. I get the error:
 "*SELECT list expression references consignment_items.receiver_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:1]*"

[screenshot of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tce8F.png)

```
SELECT
table1.field1 AS alias1,
table1.field2,
table1.field3,
table2.field4,
table2.field5 AS alias2,
STRING_AGG(table3.field9, '|') AS alias3
FROM database.table1 table1
JOIN database.table3 roles ON table1.field1 = table3.field6
JOIN database.table2 ON table1.field2 = table2.field7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`.  This will work:

```
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Thank you! That definitely worked.

Can you please educate me on why it worked or why it was needed in the query to work?

Comment: `STRING_AGG()` is an aggregation function.  It requires `GROUP BY` (if you have unaggregated columns).  BigQuery allows the use of integer position arguments for the `GROUP BY` keys (similar to `ORDER BY`).